# Knowing if a directory exists in a docker linux container from c#

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm deploying an ASP.NET Core application to a docker linux container running in Docker Desktop (I have Windows on my machine). I created the Dockerfile starting with:

```
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
  WORKDIR /app/backend
```

The creation of the image succeeded but when I run the app in the container I'm getting an Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException. I'm being able to debug using Docker Support in VS 2019 and I found out that this is returning false and throwing an exception:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("/app/backend"))
        {
            throw some custom exception;
        }
```

I tried this but it didn't work either

```
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("/app/backend");

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw some custom exception
        }
```

I can't understand why it is not working.

Comment: I think is because that your working directory is `/app/backend` and the executing dll will exists inside the backend folder in linux. So your code will look for the folder `executingPath/app/backend`. So try using `var path = Server.MapPath("~/app/backend"); if(!Directory.Exists(path))`

Comment: None of the code you have posted throws a NullReferenceException - please fix up your question

Comment: Also, I don't really understand why code has to check for existence of a dir and if not exists, throw an exception so unclear that you have to use a debugger to work it out; if the code wants to have a /app/backend dir it should just create it and then use it or at the very least throw an exception with a sensible message.. but if all the admin will do is create the folder and rerun the app, the code should create the folder itself